# How to execute function based on URL in Iron Router without any data from collection?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

What's the way to route based on Session.set without saving any data to collection? For example user inputs an URL to some site.

```js
'submit #form': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = template.find('#input').value;
    if (url)
        Session.set('url', url);
}
```

What's the route file would look like, if we want to execute function based on an URL let's say to:

```
www.example.com/download?url=http://youtube.com
```

and execute function based on this input from an URL?

I don't like my current way of doing this. Seems to me too complicated as following:

```js
Template.formButton.events({
  'submit #form': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = template.find('#input').value;
    if (url)
        var linkId = Link.insert({
          url: url,
        });
        var route = {_id:linkId};
        Router.go('download', route);
  }
});
```

```js
this.route('download', {
  path: '/download/:_id',
  where: 'client',
  data: function() {
    return Link.findOne(this.params._id);
  },
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    var data = this.data();
    if (data)
      var url = data.url;
      console.log(url);
      Meteor.call(getUrl, url, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result)
        this.next();
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Apart than the fact that your link should be url-encoded, I don't see any issue with doing that. `:_id` is not the only parameter name possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MasterAM already said, just urlencode your url and provide it directly to your route, but as a query parameter, not a path component:

Template:

```js
Template.formButton.events({
  'submit #form': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = template.find('#input').value;
    if (url)
        Router.go('download?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
  }
});
```

Router:

```js
this.route('download', {
  path: '/download',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
      var url = decodeURIComponent(this.params.query.url);
      console.log(url);
      Meteor.call(getUrl, url, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result)
        this.next();
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. I just edited incorrect apostrophe after 'download?url=', added decodeURIComponent  and changed param to params. If you can edit it so others can benefit from your answer too.